# Inverse Fourier Transform of transfer functions

Tags: fourier, laplace-transform

I want to find the inverse fourier transform of the following transfer function :
$$
H(iw) = \frac{10 + (iw)}{4 - w^2 + 4(iw)}
$$
So my first idea was to replace \$iw\$ with \$s\$. Then convert this into some euler formula. This gives me : 
$$
h(t) = \frac{10 + s}{4-w^2 + 4s}
$$
But I can't really factor the denominator since there are 2 different variables. So how exactly do I proceed?

I know the inverse fourier transform formula is \$0.5(pi)\$ * integral of \$h(t)*e^(st) \$ from negative to positive infinitiy.

Comment: To get inline LaTeX, you need to use backslash and then dollar.

Comment: [Also posted on Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1679738/14578).
Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, \$s=j\omega\$, so
$$ \omega = \frac{s}{j}= \frac{js}{j^2} = -j s $$
Substituting that into your transfer function
$$ H(j\omega) = \frac{10+j\omega}{4-\omega^2+4j\omega} = \frac{10+s}{4-\left(\frac{s}{j}\right)^2+4s} = \frac{10+s}{4+4s+s^2},$$
since \$\frac{1}{j^2} = \frac{1}{-1}=-1\$.

In order to find \$h(t)\$, you need to calculate
$$ h(t) = L^{-1}\{H(s)\} = \frac{1}{2\pi j}\lim_{T\to\infty}\int_{s=-\gamma-jT}^{\gamma+jT}H(s)e^{st}\; ds.$$

You can do this by using Cauchy's residue theorem, or else make it easier for yourself and use tables. In this case, 
$$ 4+4s+s^2 = (s+2)^2, $$
so with \$s'=s+2=s-(-2)\$,
$$ H(s) = \frac{s'+8}{(s')^2}=\frac{1}{s'}+\frac{8}{(s')^2},$$
and the rest should be trivial.

### Update

We have
$$\begin{align} 
L\{ a f(t) + b g(t) \} &= a\,F(s)+b\,G(s) & \text{(linearity)}\\
L\{1\} &= \frac{1}{s} & \text{(constant)}\\
L\{t\} &= \frac{1}{s^2} & \text{(first order)}\\
L\{t^n\} &= \frac{n!}{s^n} & \text{($n$-th order)}\\
L\{e^{kt}f(t)\} &= F(s-k) &  \text{($s$-plane shift)}
\end{align}
$$
so setting \$F(s) = s^{-1}\$, then \$f(t)=1\$ and 
$$ L^{-1} \left\{ \frac{1}{s-(-2)} \right\} = e^{-2t},$$
and setting \$F(s) = s^{-2}\$ for the next term, then \$f(t)=t\$ and
$$ L^{-1} \left\{ \frac{8}{(s-(-2))^2} \right\} = 8t\,e^{-2t},$$
so you end up with
$$ h(t) = L^{-1}\{H(s)\} = (1+8t)e^{-2t} $$

Comment: Can you help me continue from there as well?

Comment: the change of variable is not really useful!

Comment: Not useful? \$L\{e^{kt}f(t)\} = F(s-k)\$. Look at Chu's answer, and you'll notice the \$e^{-2t}\$ factor.

Answer (score 1):

Write \$H(s)\$ as $$H(s)= \frac{10}{s^2+4s+4}\:+\:\frac{s}{s^2+4s+4}$$ 
The time response for the first term is easily found from the Laplace Transform tables \$\small (\zeta=1\$, \$ \omega_n \small =2)\$; then differentiate this and divide by 10 for the time response of the second term.

This gives:
$$h(t)=e^{-2t}(1+8t)$$